# Can an US H1 Visa be transfered before its beginning date of October 1st

Tags: usa, h1-visa

I recently got my H1-B approved which should start from October 1st, but unfortunately I got laid off from that company too in August.

I have found a new job with another firm and wondering if I can start working for them starting October 1, 2014 and get my current visa transferred to the new company.

How feasible is it?

Comment: Welcome to expatriates.SE.  How can you be laid off from the company where you haven't started yet?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion there. Actually I had been working for them when they filed my H1 but they had to let me go due to budget issues.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can. The new company should file a H1B application exempt from quota based on your current H1b approval. Their lawyer should know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you can not work for new employer until you get approval, If this is your first H1b and transferring from CPT/OPT than you can work with new employer with your current CPT/OPT.

Your new employer can file transfer for you and that may help you to transfer your H1B easily. Please talk to a lawyer and discuss your case and see if they can provide you exact legal guidelines.

Hope this help you

Comment: Removed advertisement, and the OP will not need to pay for it anyway since it is illegal for employee to pay for anything related to H1b (except for premium processing).

Comment: @littleadv the company can company can ask the employee to bear the attorney fees, but they are legally bound to pay the application fee.